# Android Intent usage (Call_action & new_task_launch)

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I have faced the following error while running my application.
The code of my app is

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Button callButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id. callButton);
    callButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    { 
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
          Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.CALL_ACTION,Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
          callIntent.setLaunchFlags(Intent.NEW_TASK_LAUNCH);
          startActivity(callIntent);
       }
     });

   }
```

The problem that I am facing is the `CALL_ACTION` and the `NEW_TASK_LAUNCH` are giving me an error informing me that they are not fields. Could anyone please resolve this?

Comment: If you accept more answers, you might get more answers...

Answer (score 0):

You simply write it wrong, obviously, it's not a field. Aren't you getting error message in your IDE? `CALL_ACTIVITY` should be `ACTION_CALL` and `NEW_TASK_LAUNCH` should be `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. Please read the [Documentation](https://d.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) first.

Comment: it is not the guy's fault if some douches at Google decide to rename their constants. http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#4